# Android/Python How to verify Signature SHA256withRSA and PKCS1 Padding

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, rsa, digital-signature

I'm new member, I have waited two days to find solution verify signature from android client to python server.
First I create Key pair and generate signature from private key. Thank you pedrofb I have updated full code. verify done in python server.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = null;
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        //keyStore.deleteEntry("key1");
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
        try {
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("key1", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                    .setKeySize(2048)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                    .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1);
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(builder.build());
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("key1", null);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate("key1").getPublicKey();
        String publicKeyStr = Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Log.d("Hahaha", publicKeyStr);
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        String data = "haha";
        signature.update(data.getBytes());
        byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
        String signatureBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(signatureBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Log.d("Hahaha", signatureBase64);
        Signature verifySignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        verifySignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        verifySignature.update(data.getBytes());
        boolean isVerify = verifySignature.verify(Base64.decode(signatureBase64, Base64.NO_WRAP));
        Log.d("Hahaha", isVerify + "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String sha256(String rawString){
    MessageDigest shaDigest;
    byte[] data;
    try {
        data = rawString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        shaDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    shaDigest.update(data);
    return toHex(shaDigest.digest());
}

public static String toHex(byte[] tmp) {
    char hexDigits[] =
            {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                    'e', 'f'};
    int nBytesLen = tmp.length;
    char str[] = new char[nBytesLen * 2];
    int k = 0;
    for (byte byte0 : tmp) {
        str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf];
        str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 & 0xf];
    }
    return new String(str);
}
```

and Server, I use `PKCS1_v1_5` to verify signature, it will be sent from android client

```py
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode

keyDER = b64decode(open('public.der').read())
key = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
message = "haha"
h = SHA256.new(message)
print h.hexdigest()
signature = b64decode(open('signature.der').read())
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
if verifier.verify(h, signature):
    print "The signature is authentic."
else:
    print "The signature is not authentic."
```

I have check data hashed both client and server, it's same, but verifier.verify return false, `public.der` is value of variable `PublicKeyStr` and `signature.der` is value of variable `SignatureBase64`
Please help me.

Comment: The data is *not* the same, it is "Hahaha" on the Java side and "haha" on the python side.

Comment: You have several errors 1) You are hashing twice in Java code and signing and hex value. Change `signature.update(sha256(data).getBytes());` with `signature.update(data.getBytes());` and `verifySignature.update(sha256(data).getBytes());` with `verifySignature.update(data.getBytes());` 2) Remove `.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)` 3) You should  create the the keypair one, not each time `onCreate` is called

Comment: Thank you, but client I verify true, verifySignature I create only check it works from android. The data I sign both java side and python side is "haha". h.hexdigest() in python and sha256(data).getBytes() return same value.

Comment: 3) You should create the the keypair one, not each time onCreate is called. You are right, so I always update keypair to public.der and signature.der after onCreate call by debug mode.

Comment: Thank you  pedrofb. I have resolved this issue, but I have a question for you? I think we should hash 'haha' both client and server. but why we keep 'haha' and sign it in client but server must be hash by SHA256?

Comment: @hai, I added the explanation as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved in comments] You have several errors in your Java code

1) In the Java code, you are digesting the message twice with SHA256 and signing an hex value, not the binary message.

In java, `SHA256withRSA` performs several operations, first applies the SHA256 digest algorithm to the message and then applies the RSA PKCS # 1 v1.5 algorithm. In python (or in other languages) it can be done programmatically in two steps

Change

```
signature.update(sha256(data).getBytes());
verifySignature.update(sha256(data).getBytes());
```

with

```
signature.update(data.getBytes());
verifySignature.update(data.getBytes());
```

2) Remove `.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)`. This is an encryption parameter not appliable to digital signature

3) You should create the the keypair once, not each time `onCreate` is called